# バリュードメインで取得したドメインをさくらでDNSサーバー設定したメールアドレスの利用とワードプレスへの影響について

Tags: dns

はじめまして、荒牧と申します。
事業で使っているワードプレス、独自ドメインのメールアドレス、メルマガスタンドについて
技術的な疑問がでてきてしまい、ご質問させていただきます。

1.以前の状況
いま、さくらのレンタルサーバーでワードプレスのブログを運用しています。
独自ドメインはバリュードメインで取得し、さくらインターネットでドメイン設定をして、
その独自ドメインのメールアドレスを使っています。

[バリュードメインで取得したドメインをさくらサーバーで使う方法](https://www.jaskun.com/server/sakuraserver/valuedmain-sakuraserver/)

2.状況の変化
事業の状況の変化で、メルマガスタンドをマイスピーに変更しました。
これまで使っていた独自ドメインのメールアドレスを配信メールアドレスに設定しようと
したところ、
「メールアドレスのSPF設定がされていません」
と注意されてしまいました。
そのままでは到達率に悪影響があるとのことで、
なんとか設定しようと思うのですが、

マイスピーのガイダンスいわく、
さくらインターネット以外で取得したドメインの場合、
①別のネームサーバーに切り替え　するか、
②上記のドメインをつかわず別の新規ドメインを手配する必要がある、
とのことでした。

[さくらインターネットで管理しているドメインのSPF設定をするには？ | MyASP（マイスピー）ユーザーマニュアル](https://docs.myasp.jp/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f/%e3%81%95%e3%81%8f%e3%82%89%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%83%8d%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e7%ae%a1%e7%90%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%83%89%e3%83%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%81%aesp/)

3.問題点・疑問
これまで馴染みのメールアドレスであるため変更したくないのですが、
ひとくちに別のネームサーバーに切り替える、といわれてもよくわかりません。

4.仮説とご質問
仮説としては、
バリュードメインでサーバーを契約して、DNS設定すればよいようにも思えるのですが、

[DNS情報・URL転送の設定 | VALUE-DOMAIN ユーザーガイド](https://www.value-domain.com/userguide/manual/moddns/)

そのときに、
さくらのレンタルサーバーにアプしてあるブログにどのような影響が
起こってしまうのかわからず、前に進めない状況です。

上記の点につきまして、
どのように解決していったらいいのか、
アドバイスいただけましたら幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

確認ですが、バリュードメインで取得したドメインのネームサーバーの設定で、「ns1.dns.ne.jp」および「ns2.dns.ne.jp」を指定して、さくらのレンタルサーバーで利用しているという理解でよいでしょうか。
この場合、さくらのレンタルサーバーではDNSレコードを追加したり、編集したりする機能がないため、下記の2とおりの方法が考えられます。

1. バリュードメインでDNSレコードを管理する。
2. 別のドメインを取得して利用する。

1つ目の方法の場合、ネームサーバーをバリュードメインのネームサーバーに切り替えた上で、Aレコード等、すべてのレコードを自分で管理する必要がありますが、ある程度柔軟な管理が可能かと思います。
ちなみに、バリュードメインのネームサーバーを利用するためだけに別途サーバーを契約する必要はありません。
しかし、さくらのレンタルサーバーで無料のSSLを利用している場合、さくらのネームサーバー以外のネームサーバーでは、証明書の取得や更新ができないため、サーバーを変更するか、2つ目の方法（別のドメインを取得して利用する）になってしまうかと思います。
2つ目の方法の場合は、質問者さんがおっしゃるように、メールアドレスが変わってしまいます。
以上、参考になれば幸いです。